# Click to Openlayers shows blank pop up - All Formats for Images Works

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, popup

I am totally new to GeoServer and all this WebServer stuff, so please understand that all the gray hairs on my head over the last 2 weeks are from trying to get this all set up and working.

When I select my layer to preview with OpenLayers, I get a pop up that opens and is blank, except for the bounding box and the text to the bottom left and right. Not sure how to fix this so I click and have it show the map item, which in this case is a shapefile.

I should note that I can select the 'All Formats' form the Layer Preview and if it is an image, I can see and/or download the shape as a jpg, pdf, tiff, gif, so I know the data is being read, just not displayed.

Anyone else have this issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is a configuration issue wherby I had the Proxy URL identified in the Global Settings, as well in the Edit Workspace.

The Proxy URL only needs to be in the Global Settings.